# String concatenate/shorten algorithm

Tags: c#, string, algorithm

I want to publish server-messages on Twitter, for our clients.
Unfortunately, Twitter only allows posting 140 Chars or less. This is a shame.

Now, I have to write an algorithm that concatenates the different messages from the server together, but shortens them to a max of 140 characters.

It's pretty tricky.

---

### CODE

```
static string concatinateStringsWithLength(string[] strings, int length, string separator) {
    // This is the maximum number of chars for the strings
    // We have to subtract the separators
    int maxLengthOfAllStrings = length - ((strings.Length - 1) * separator.Length);

    // Here we save all shortenedStrings
    string[] cutStrings = new string[strings.Length];

    // This is the average length of all the strings
    int averageStringLenght = maxLengthOfAllStrings / strings.Length;

    // Now we check how many strings are longer than the average string
    int longerStrings = 0;
    foreach (string singleString in strings)
    {
        if (singleString.Length > averageStringLenght)
        {
            longerStrings++;
        }
    }

    // If a string is smaller than the average string, we can more characters to the longer strings
    int maxStringLength = averageStringLenght;
    foreach (string singleString in strings)
    {
        if (averageStringLenght > singleString.Length)
        {
            maxStringLength += (int)((averageStringLenght - singleString.Length) * (1.0 / longerStrings));
        }
    }

    // Finally we shorten the strings and save them to the array
    int i = 0;
    foreach (string singleString in strings)
    {
        string shortenedString = singleString;
        if (singleString.Length > maxStringLength)
        {
            shortenedString = singleString.Remove(maxStringLength);
        }

        cutStrings[i] = shortenedString;
        i++;
    }


    return String.Join(separator, cutStrings);
}
```

---

### Problem with this

This algorithm works, but it's not very optimized.
It uses less characters than it actually could.

The main problem with this is that the variable `longerStrings` is relative to the `maxStringLength`, and backwards.

This means if I change `longerStrings`, `maxStringLength` gets changed, and so on and so on.
I'd have to make a while loop and do this until there are no changes, but I don't think that's necessary for such a simple case.

Can you give me a clue on how to continue?

Or maybe there already exists something similar?

Thanks!

---

### EDIT

The messages I get from the server look like this:

- Message

  - Subject
  - Date
  - Body
- Message

  - Subject
  - Date
  - Body

And so on.

What I want is to concatenate the strings with a separator, in this case a semi-colon.
There should be a max length. The long strings should be shortened first.

### Example

This is a subject
This is the body and is a bit lon...
25.02.2013

This is a s...
This is the...
25.02.2013

I think you get the idea ;)

Comment: Can you specify when and how strings should be shortened? It can maybe be derived from the code but that is not always reliable.

Comment: Could you provide some example of input and output?

Comment: What does this algorithm have to do with the 140 characters you have mentioned? Sorry if I have mis-read something.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've added more information

Comment: @yBee Take a look at the example. The whole string must be maximal 140 chars long, because Twitter does not allow longer posts.

Comment: @LukeHennerley Twitter only allows 140 char posts. I have to merge as much information as possible. The message contains different properties, I have to concatenate them and shorten the long ones so it fits.

Comment: @NSAddict I don't understand the need for all of this, why not make one long string then take 140 characters from the string at a time?

Comment: @LukeHennerley One post contains a few properties, like a subject, a body, a date, and so on. If you just make one long string and cut it to 140 characters, there will be whole properties just cut away. The properties should be cut evenly.

Comment: You mean sth like this: `var strings = new[] {"This is a subject", "This is the body and is a bit lon...", "25.02.2013"};
            var result = Concatenate(strings, 11, ";");` and the method body: `return String.Concat(strings.Select(s => String.Concat(new string(s.Take(maxLength).Concat(s.Length < maxLength ? new char[0] : new[] {'.', '.', '.'}).ToArray()), separator)));`? According to your example.

Comment: @yBee No. `var strings = new[] {"This is a subject", "This is the body and is a bit longer", "25.02.2013"}; var result = Concatenate(strings, tolazytocounttheoutputrightnow, ";");` => **Output:** This is a subject;This is the body and is a bit lon...;25.02.2013

Comment: @NSAddict: `var strings = new[] {"This is a subject", "This is the body and is a bit to long long long", "25.02.2013"};
            var result = Concatenate(strings, 36, ";");` --> `return String.Concat(strings.Select(s => String.Concat(new string(s.Take(maxLength).Concat(s.Length < maxLength ? new char[0] : new[] {'.', '.', '.'}).ToArray()), separator)));`. Correct?

Comment: @yBee Yes, but my main problem is how to calculate `maxLength`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Five times slower than yours (in our simple example) but should use maximum avaliable space (no critical values checking):

```
static string Concatenate(string[] strings, int maxLength, string separator)
{
    var totalLength = strings.Sum(s => s.Length);
    var requiredLength = totalLength - (strings.Length - 1)*separator.Length;

    // Return if there is enough place.
    if (requiredLength <= maxLength)
        return String.Concat(strings.Take(strings.Length - 1).Select(s => s + separator).Concat(new[] {strings.Last()}));

    // The problem...
    var helpers = new ConcatenateInternal[strings.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < helpers.Length; i++)
        helpers[i] = new ConcatenateInternal(strings[i].Length);

    var avaliableLength = maxLength - (strings.Length - 1)*separator.Length;
    var charsInserted = 0;
    var currentIndex = 0;

    while (charsInserted != avaliableLength)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
        {
            if (charsInserted == avaliableLength)
                break;

            if (currentIndex >= strings[i].Length)
            {
                helpers[i].Finished = true;
                continue;
            }

            helpers[i].StringBuilder.Append(strings[i][currentIndex]);
            charsInserted++;
        }
        currentIndex++;
    }

    var unified = new StringBuilder(avaliableLength);
    for (var i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!helpers[i].Finished)
        {
            unified.Append(helpers[i].StringBuilder.ToString(0, helpers[i].StringBuilder.Length - 3));
            unified.Append("...");
        }
        else
        {
            unified.Append(helpers[i].StringBuilder.ToString());
        }

        if (i < strings.Length - 1)
        {
            unified.Append(separator);
        }
    }

    return unified.ToString();
}
```

And *ConcatenateInternal*:

```
class ConcatenateInternal
{
    public StringBuilder StringBuilder { get; private set; }
    public bool Finished { get; set; }

    public ConcatenateInternal(int capacity)
    {
        StringBuilder = new StringBuilder(capacity);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's with the `ConcatenateInternal` class? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NSAddict: I store there boolean which indicates that the string is full and not require further processing and also ellipsis at the end. I couldn't use Tuple due to editing the value of Finished while processing.

Comment: Sir, thanks a lot, works perfectly. The performance is ok. Now upvote guys ;)

Comment: I thought some more people were gonna up-vote :( I'm sorry, still an awesome answer ;)